# What does boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket>::shutdown() do?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

The extensive [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ssl__stream/shutdown/overload1.html) helpfully says:

> This function is used to shut down SSL on the stream. The function call will block until SSL has been shut down or an error occurs.

Which leaves me with these questions:

1. Does this close the actual connection too?
2. If not, how do I do that?
3. Can I reuse the stream by calling `boost::asio::connect(theSocket.lowest_layer(), ...` again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the covers, asio calls `SSL_Shutdown()` in the underlying OpenSSL library:

The documentation for which is here:

https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/ssl/SSL_shutdown.html

... and contains the following ominous text:

> The behaviour of SSL_shutdown() additionally depends on the underlying BIO.

However, my understanding of things is that the `ssl::stream` object is not a socket (by design) but more like a protocol layer that sits on top of a `Stream`-like object. Thus the `asio::ssl` layer has no knowledge of its `next_layer()` other than that it must support the free functions `read`,`write`, `async_read` and `async_write`. Certainly no knowledge about whether the layer supports the concept of `shutdown()` (or even `close()`).

Therefore I would expect the underlying socket, given by `lowest_layer()` to still be open when `shutdown()` returns. Furthermore, I would expect that `shutdown()` will not have been called on the `lowest_layer()`. You'll want to do this after `ssl::shutdown` returns, or in the handler passed to  `ssl::async_shutdown`